# Where do you use generators feature in your python code?

Tags: python, generator

I have studied generators feature and i think i got it but i would like to understand where i could apply it in my code.

I have in mind the following example i read in "Python essential reference" book:

```
# tail -f
 def tail(f):
  f.seek(0,2) 
  while True:
   line = f.readline() 
   if not line: 
     time.sleep(0.1)
     continue
   yield line
```

Do you have any other effective example where generators are the best tool for the job like tail -f?

How often do you use generators feature and in which kind of functionality\part of program do you usually apply it?

Comment: Please make this a community wiki question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use them a lot when I implement scanners (tokenizers) or when I iterate over data containers.

Edit: here is a demo tokenizer I used for a C++ syntax highlight program:

```
whitespace = ' \t\r\n'
operators = '~!%^&*()-+=[]{};:\'"/?.,<>\\|'

def scan(s):
    "returns a token and a state/token id"
    words = {0:'', 1:'', 2:''} # normal, operator, whitespace
    state = 2 # I pick ws as first state
    for c in s:
        if c in operators:
            if state != 1:
                yield (words[state], state)
                words[state] = ''
            state = 1
            words[state] += c
        elif c in whitespace:
            if state != 2:
                yield (words[state], state)
                words[state] = ''
            state = 2
            words[state] += c
        else:
            if state != 0:
                yield (words[state], state)
                words[state] = ''
            state = 0
            words[state] += c
    yield (words[state], state)
```

Usage example:

```
>>> it = scan('foo(); i++')
>>> it.next()
('', 2)
>>> it.next()
('foo', 0)
>>> it.next()
('();', 1)
>>> it.next()
(' ', 2)
>>> it.next()
('i', 0)
>>> it.next()
('++', 1)
>>>
```

Comment: Could you post some simple snippet of tokenizers?

Comment: @systempuntoout, ok, I posted a sample.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever your code would either generate an **unlimited number of values** or more generally if **too much memory** would be consumed by generating the whole list at first.

Or if it is likely that you **don't** iterate over the **whole generated list** (and the list is very large). I mean there is no point in generating every value first (and waiting for the generation) if it is not used.

My latest encounter with generators was when I implemented a linear recurrent sequence (LRS) like e.g. the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: -1: Sounds to me more like a description of iterators in general, not generator functions, so it misses the point. Why did this answer get any upvotes?

Comment: @nikow: Yes it is more general, but I wouldn't say that it is a *description* of iterators. It is an abstract description about in which situations generators could be useful. Generators are some kind of iterators.. :)

Answer (score 2):

In all cases where I have algorithms that read anything, I use generators exclusively.

Why?

Layering in filtering, mapping and reduction rules is so much easier in a context of multiple generators.

Example:

```
def discard_blank( source ):
    for line in source:
        if len(line) == 0:
            continue
        yield line

def clean_end( source ):
    for line in source:
        yield line.rstrip()

def split_fields( source ):
    for line in source;
        yield line.split()

def convert_pos( tuple_source, position ):
    for line in tuple_source:
        yield line[:position]+int(line[position])+line[position+1:]

with open('somefile','r') as source:
    data= convert_pos( split_fields( discard_blank( clean_end( source ) ) ), 0 )
    total= 0
    for l in data:
        print l
        total += l[0]
    print total
```

My preference is to use many small generators so that a small change is not disruptive to the entire process chain.

Comment: So you are just using generator functions as a convenient notation for iterator decorators. I think the example of Nick D is much better, since it highlights the continuation aspect.

Comment: @J. T. Hurley: I don't know what "just as well" means, but generators don't create intermediate results, where functions generally do.  Nested generators are a kind of map-reduce pipeline.

Comment: @nikow: I'm not interested in continuations.  I'm interested in breaking up a big (possibly messy) operation into small map-reduce style steps.

Comment: @S.Lott: Continuations are an interesting feature (especially with the newer coroutine functionality), so its too bad that you are not interested in them ;-)

Comment: @nikow: I'm not interested in them *for the purposes of this answer*.  They're an interesting feature.  I've never used them except as an exercise.  I have always used stateful, callable objects instead of continuations.  But that gets beyond this specific answer.  My point was not to cover all possible uses of generators.  My point was to answer the question: "any other effective example where generators are the best tool for the job".

Answer (score 1):

In general, to separate data aquisition (which might be complicated) from consumption. In particular:

- to concatenate results of several b-tree queries - the db part generates and executes the queries `yield`-ing records from each one, the consumer only sees single data items arriving.
- buffering (read-ahead ) - the generator fetches data in blocks and yields single elements from each block. Again, the consumer is separated from the gory details.

Generators can also work as coroutines. You can pass data **into** them using `nextval=g.next(data)` on the 'consumer' side and `data = yield(nextval)` on the generator side. In this case the generator and its consumer 'swap' values. You can even make `yield` throw an exception within the generator context: `g.throw(exc)` does that.